# Invoking Soap service fails in java, works in soapui

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soapui, icmp

I'm trying to consume a soap service in java.
If I import the wsdl url in SOAPUI, I get the :`java.net.ConnectException connection timed out` exception.

I saved the WSDL to a file and successfully inported it into SOAPUI.
In SOAPUI, I'm able to consume it.

In java however, i still get the `java.net.ConnectException connection timed out exception`
when trying to consume it, having tried with a number of different libraries that work on other webservices in the same network.

I've also tried putting my entreprise proxy in java with no effect.

However, if i put a local proxy, like Fiddler, in front of java, I cat invoke the webservice successfully. The server where it's hosted has ping (ICMP) blocked.
Event if I make a simple get for the WSDl address I get the `java.net.ConnectException connection timed out exception`.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: SoapUI uses the location from `<soap:address location="..."/>`. Are you sure your Java client uses the same URL? Seems your client is connecting to non-existing endpoint.

Comment: Yes, I'm using that same address. That's the weird part, event if I make a simple GET for the WSDL url in java, I still get the timeout, and soapui has the same behaviour when importing the wsdl

Comment: [Global Java proxy?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/proxy_setup.xml)

Comment: No, i used this:
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","url");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","80");
System.setProperty("useSystemProxies", "true");

Comment: The link isn't broken for me...

Comment: After you edited it, It was working. I just tried the way it's described in the link with the same results.